# Elastic Beanstalk over SSL on Cloudflare

Tags: ssl, parse-platform, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am using ElasticBeanStalk on AWS as part of my Parse environment. The Elastic Beanstalk URL is myparseapp.elasticbeanstalk.com. When a user registers for an account on my site ("www.example.com"), Elastic Beanstalk works its magic.

That worked fine until I enabled SSL on the soon-to-be-production website and tested it. Registration fails, and I see this in the developer console:

> parse.min.js:16 Mixed Content: The page at
>   'https://www.example.com/register.html' was loaded over HTTPS, but
>   requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint
>   'http://myparseapp.elasticbeanstalk.com/parse/users'. This request has
>   been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

I understand why I'm receiving the error. I'm not clear on how to resolve it. Everything I read says "register your domain, get an SSL cert, attach a CNAME (www) using Route 53, apply it to the load balancer. Done."

Well... 1) I already have a domain which is used for my website. 2) My SSL is being served via Cloudflare, which is where SSL terminates. 3) Why would I assign the CNAME 'www' to Elastic Beanstalk when my www.example.com is my actual website? Wouldn't using the CNAME "www" break my site? 4) My Elastic Beanstalk instance isn't behind a load balancer.

Do I need to create a separate domain just for elastic beanstalk? That doesn't sound right. I could see making it a subdomain perhaps, such as parseapp.example.com.

Since I'm using Cloudflare (and I like it), I would prefer not to use Route 53 for this... but if it's my only choice, then so be it.

So, in summary, how do I access my Elastic Beanstalk app over SSL using Cloudflare?

Thank you in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Without looking at all your configuration in CloudFlare, here is how we setup our system for Parse with CloudFlare and AWS.

If Parse Server instance (on `elasticbeanstalk`) cannot handle HTTPS:

- Setup a subdomain `parse.example.com` with CloudFlare as a CNAME with an alias of `myparseapp.elasticbeanstalk.com`.
- Make sure the cloud icon is orange (turned on).
- Go to the Crypto tab in CloudFlare and make sure it is set to `Flexible`. Doing so will have all requests to any `example.com` domain go through CloudFlare which will use CloudFlare's SSL, but then CloudFlare will route that request to your `elasticbeanstalk.com` in either HTTP or HTTPS.
- Make sure your Parse Server URL is now set to `https://parse.example.com/parse` (as defined in your CNAME). This will make your Ajax request look like: `https://parse.example.com/parse/users` instead of the previous URL.

If you can setup SSL certificates on your instance, you can configure CloudFlare to provide you with `Origin Certificates` that you can install on your instance (see `Crypto` tab, under `Origin Certificates`). Those certificates are there to secure the connection between CloudFlare and the origin server, in your case ElasticBeanstalk. If you do this, then you should still follow the steps above, but instead of selecting `Flexible` on SSL, use `Full`.

Comment: You are a life-saver, my friend. Worked great! Thanks!

Comment: doesn't this mean his traffic is still going over http in production?

Comment: man, you're amazing...